# Перевод хранимых процедур с СУБД Sybase ASE на Oracle Database

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, stored-procedures, sybase

Как легко можно перевести хранимых процедуры с T-SQL (СУБД Sybase ASE) на PL/SQL (Oracle Database)? Может есть какие-то утилиты для этого?

Comment: Диалекты различных СУБД различаются настолько сильно, что автоматизированный перевод возможен лишь для самых простейших кодов. Обычно же всё приходится переделывать вручную, причём чаще даже не переделывать, а переписывать с нуля - всё одно получается и быстрее, и надёжнее.

Comment: Может кому полезно будет https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/sybase/migrate_sybase_otn.htm